# Is it possible to have a large image above the content node in Drupal?

Tags: css, drupal, layout, drupal-theming, drupal-blocks

I'm trying to replicate pages like the following using Drupal:

http://www.ams-neve.com/Products/Outboard/1073LB/1073LB.aspx

My problem is that I'd like the image at the top (which changes depending on which page you're on) to be part of the main content node, while the menu on the left is a sidebar region.

I'd like to have a 'product' content type where I can write the main copy, include linked files, etc. plus have a 'header image' which would be what appears at the top of the page.

I have the feeling that it can't be done like this because I'd essentially need bits of the node to be rendered into different blocks.  If I theme the node template to wrap a div around the header image I can't figure out a way to have that moved to the top of the page and displace the left sidebar down.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible, or suggest an alternative route.
There are a lot of products so I need it to be a simple method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I used was to create a Views Slideshow Block in Views.  It pulled the header_image field from my node by looking at the page it was on.  I put this block into the header of my page.

Anyone else looking at this should also check out Display Suite.  You can do a lot of cool stuff with that.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not getting it wrong you are having problems with the default way in which `drupal` blocks work. Have you tried [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels)? It's an awesome plugin to work with `drupal` which let you create pages in a really flexible way.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have used panels, but I need hundreds of product nodes to load in the same way.  I think with panels I'd have to create individual pages for each node and I couldn't make a single change to effect all of them at once.

I'm thinking perhaps I can define a header block, then create a view block that takes the page url as an argument, finds the images associated with that node and displays them in the block.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom field for your 'Product' content type that is an image or a text field to a URL for the header image. Just use CSS to place them where you'd like.

Alternatively, check out these links, I think they are what you are looking for.

http://drupal.org/project/headerimage

http://drupal.org/project/sections